# fetch JSON (http get) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want run it using http get, but it not show nothing, Where is the error?. Angular http.get easier to get JSON and doing ngFor and show, but on React is little special. So, in conclusion I don't like do a simple "import data from './data.json'", I need load json from the cloud.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {

    // 1.JSON
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        items: [],
      };
    }
    // 2. JSON
    componentJSON() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ items: data.items }))
    }

  render() {

    // this.componentJSON = this.componentJSON.bind(this);
    this.setState({ items: data})

     // 3. JSON
    //  const { items } = this.state;

    return (
      <Router> 
        <div className="App">  

          <ul>
            {items.map(item =>
              <li key={item.title}>
                {item.title}
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>

        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Working now!,

Thanks anyway friends!

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items : []
        };

        // You should bind this object to componentWillMount method, other setState was not working
        this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
    }


    // This method is call before component will mounted
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then( data => this.setState({ items : data }) );
    }

    render() {

       const { items } = this.state;

        return (
            <ul>
                {items.map(item =>
                    <li key={item.title}>
                        {item.title}
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` is react lifecycle method and is already bound when you call `super()`. You only need to explicitly bind methods you create yourself.

Comment: The react docs explicitly discourage side effects in `componentWillMount` (I think the method might be deprecated soon in favour of constructor), instead use `componentDidMount` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

In your function you are assuming that the context is the class, but its not, its not how js works, so when you are trying to use this.setState it would not work because the context of the function doesnt have any function called setState.
A simple way of solving this is binding the function to the class, by simply adding the following line in the ctor:

this.componentJSON = this.componentJSON.bind(this);

Comment: I added it intro render() {}, working clean on console but no show nothing, Angular 4.3/5 it's so easy using http.get

Comment: Calling your API in your render function will mean that you API is called every time there is a re-render which happens every time the state is updated. You are setting the state in your API call so you are causing an infinite loop. As I mentioned in my answer, call the function in `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `componentJSON` function.

It is best to do this within `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.componentJSON()
}
```

This will get called when the component is rendered in the browser.

It is a common mistake to call your API within `componentWillMount()` but this will make your API call happen twice.

As mentioned in my other comment, be careful about calling your API in your render function as it will mean that you API is called every time there is a re-render. A re-render happens after setting state and since you are setting state in your API call, it will cause an infinite loop

Comment: Doesn't it depends whether you want to call API before/after components mounts?

Answer (score -1):

Use `componentDidMount`

```
  componentDidMount ()
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits }))
  }
```

Comment: You can explain me, please.

Comment: Updated answer, you must use `componentDidMount`

Comment: This is incorrect. It does not need to be an arrow function. You can still use `componentDidMount(){ this.componentJSON() }`